# Помогите в Python

Tags: python

в моей программе надо представить что есть шахматная доска 8x8
Тоесть A1 клетка - черная, A2 белая;
B1 - белая, B2 - чёрная и т.д. до H8
В программе мы вводим клетку например:
Входные данные №1:
A1
Вывод №1:
BLACK
Входные данные №2:
B1
Вывод №1:
WHITE
Помогите на основе моего кода:

```
a = input() # ввод данных 
a1 = str(a[0]) # вырезаем букву
a2 = int(a[1]) # вырезаем число
text = "BLACK"
if a1 == 'A' or 'C' or 'E' or 'G':
    if a2 % 2 == 0: # проверка на целое число
        text = "WHITE"
else:
    if a1 == 'B' or 'D' or 'F' or 'H':
        if a2 % 2 == 1: # проверка на не целое число
            text = "WHITE"
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша главная ошибка тут:

```
if a1 == 'A' or 'C' or 'E' or 'G':
```

Расставим скобки:

```
if (((a1 == 'A') or 'C') or 'E') or 'G':
```

Что такое `or 'C'`? К сожалению, Питон не выдаёт предупреждение когда вы строку ставите на место где должно быть булево выражение. Любая непустая строка приводится к `True`:

```
if (((a1 == 'A') or True) or True) or True:
```

И всё это выражение можно заменить на:

```
if True:
```

Простейшая поправка такая:

```
if a1 == 'A' or a1 == 'C' or a1 == 'E' or a1 == 'G':
```

Есть и более продвинутые техники. Но для начала годится и так.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = input() # ввод данных 
a1 = str(a[0]) # вырезаем букву
a2 = int(a[1]) # вырезаем число
text = "BLACK"
if a1 in ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G']:
    if a2 % 2 == 1: # проверка на целое число
        text = "WHITE"
else:
    if a2 % 2 == 0: # проверка на не целое число
        text = "WHITE"
print(text)
```

```
if ("ABCDEFG".index(a[0])+int(a[1]))%2:
    print("BLACK")
else:
    print("WHITE")
```

Comment: `["WHITE", "BLACK"][("ABCDEFG".index(a[0])+int(a[1]))%2]`

Comment: Можете мой вариант как то подкоректировать?

Comment: Просто ошибки исправить пжлст....

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input() 
if (ord(a[0]) + int(a[1])) % 2 == 0:
    text = "WHITE"
else:
    text = "BLACK"
print(text)
```